# Meteor update mongodb from client side

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, permissions

I built an app using Meteor and was surprised that I could update my Meteor.user() collection from the client side.

In my collections.js file i have:

```
Meteor.users.allow({
update: function(userId, doc) {
    return false;
}
});
```

I navigated to a page where only a user with `isAdmin: true` can access and typed in my client console:

`Meteor.users.update({_id: 'adsfasdf'}, {$set: {isAdmin: true}});`

Immediately afterwards, the admin page loaded.

The console output was:

`Meteor.users.update({_id: 'adsfasdf'}, {$set: {isAdmin: true}});
1
debug.js:41 update failed: Access denied`

Any ideas why this happened?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you update a Mongo collection client side. The update happens first on the client-side `minimongo` collection. Then the `autorun` reruns with the new **client-side** changes. After that the changes are pushed to the server over DDP. Here's where you are getting your error. The `autorun` isn't rerun after the error happens.

So basically you are relying on client-side data to decide on whether or not to render the admin page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My admin controller does the checking to see if the user is an admin - does this mean the controller also uses client side data? Here's my admin controller: ``onBeforeAction: function () {
    var currUser = Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId());
    if(currUser) {
        if (!currUser.isAdmin) {
            console.log("");
        } else {
            this.next();
        }
    }
    }``

Comment: When you use `iron-router` you normally place all of that stuff inside `client/routes.js` or something. This means that the code for `client-side` routes is run on the client. So the answer is **yes**.

Comment: if i check for the `isAdmin` attribute in routes.js, would it still use client side data? Thx

Comment: Yes, doing that stuff client-side (which also means with data coming from the client) is inherit to iron-router's architecture.